# Error "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" while building large package in VS2010 SP1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, packaging

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 to create a setup package. i added about 3.2GB files to my package. but when i `build` the project i got this error after few seconds:

```
Error Could not find file 'D:\saj\repo\23.zip' 
'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.'   
D:\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Saj Setup\Saj Setup\Saj Setup.vdproj 
Saj Setup
```

but `D:\saj\repo\23.zip` file exist in that path!
What is wrong? Do i need a bigger machine to build this?

My System Details:

```
CPU: AMD Athlone 64 X2 Dual Core 4600+ 2.40G
RAM: 3.00GB
HDD Free space: 9.6G Free on C:\ and 46.0G Free on D:\ drive.
```

and [This solution](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/059d2947-fea2-492f-a734-1b4c774408ce/) not worked for me :(

Comment: If your TEMP path is on C, that's not very much free space at all.

Comment: The upper limit on the size of a setup.exe is around half a gigabyte.  Even if you do manage to get it built on your machine then it isn't likely to execute on the user's machine.  You'll need to break it up.  Try CAB files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that all setup files shall reside in RAM. Needless to say the for big installation this is a huge limit.

Your best bet would be develop a deploy package with another software.

I would suggest you [Wix](http://wix.sourceforge.net/): it is integrated with VS, it's open source and it uses MSI SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when the build process needs a lot of RAM memory and cannot get it. For example, 3 GB of RAM is not enough for a 3.2 GB package.

You can try adding more RAM to your machine.

Another solution is to increase the page file on your C: drive. You will of course need more space on C:. This way when the RAM is full, space on the C: drive will be used as virtual memory.

Comment: It's not an acceptable reason! Why should all of data come to RAM just for creating a package? InstallShield feed my needs

Comment: Not true in my experience: My RAM is at 1/4 utilization with no apparent spikes during the build process. I've seen this stock answer given by Cosmin elsewhere and would down-vote if I could.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio's Setup and Package builder sucks in large packages!

Use InstallShield or [WIX](http://wixtoolset.org).

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you using many crystal report files (*.rpt) or using many other extention files!